# Lightweight unsupervised learning method like Self organizing maps

Tags: self-organizing-maps, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to develop a lightweight system that uses an unsupervised learning method that uses system parameters such as CPU, RAM utilization to train an anomaly detection system. I could not think of anything beyond a Self organizing map. Is there any other learning technique that I can consider here?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have many options on this with SOM. The only think you could consider is whether you will do batch or sequential training, if of course the implementation that you will use offers both options. But this option mainly affects the training time (the first is much more quicker) and not the resulting map (in theory at least).

You could also select a distance function other than the Euclidian but the vast percentage of the bibliography doesn't bother with this.